# Как задать стили всем кроме первого элемента

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, интересует как задать стили всем элементам списка кроме первого, читал когда то про псевдо класс но забыл как называется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы не поддерживаете IE младше 9 версии, то вот решение:

```
li:not(:first-child) {
    color: red;
}
```

Можно также использовать `first-child`:

```
ul {
    background-color: #900;  /* будет применено к каждому ul */
}

ul:first-child {
    background-color: transparent; /* только для первого */
}
```

Для поддержки более старых браузеров можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией - объявляется общий стиль, а на первом элементе указывается класс `first-element`:

```
ul {
    background-color: #900;
}

first-element { /* этот класс необходимо указать у первого элемента */
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: IE6, серьезно? в 2016 году? :-)

Comment: @Grundy мало ли, какие корпоративные приложения, автор же не озвучил требования. 6 конечно перебор, но 8 ещё встречается

Comment: предлагаю заменить на _IE младше 9 версии_ или что-то подобное :-)

Comment: @Grundy поправил

Comment: @FeroxTL Все верно поддержка ie младше 9 версии не требуется, благодарю за оперативность.

Comment: @Grundy, FF по производительности не очень любит not first-child.

Comment: @Qwertiy Какая тогда альтернатива для FF ?

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev, использовать классы, отдельный класс для первого элемента отдельные для остальных

Comment: @Grundy Геморно как то((

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev а если поставить на все элементы списка стиль, а класс, определяющий стиль для первого элемента, указать соответственно только на первом?

Comment: @FeroxTL Думал так, но стили которые я хочу переопределить на ховере повешены. И я пришел к выводу что лучше их просто не давать первому элементу.

Comment: Альтернатива - плюс. Он работает там в 2 раза быстрее.

Comment: `first-element` - если это класс, то не хватает точки.

Answer (score 2):

```
:first-child
:first-of-type
:nth-of-type(1) 

:not(:first-child) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: в вопросе _кроме первого_ - а эти как раз _первому_ задают

Comment: для комплекта еще `nth-child` можно добавить

Comment: Поправила)

А вообще можно задавать всем стили, но первому переопределить

Answer (score 2):

```css
li { color: red; }
li:first-child { color: inherit; }

li:not(:first-child) { font-style: italic; }

li + li { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>All except first are red italic and underlined
  <li>All except first are red italic and underlined
  <li>All except first are red italic and underlined
  <li>All except first are red italic and underlined
  <li>All except first are red italic and underlined
  <li>All except first are red italic and underlined
  <li>All except first are red italic and underlined
</ul>
```